# Azure AD authentication fails with error message: "Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Authentication failed"

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've been working on a multi-tenant web application that uses Azure AD authentication, and authentication will intermittently fail with the error message: `"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Authentication failed."` To be more clear, the steps I go through are:

- Go to my web app, and click on link to go to Azure AD authentication
- Enter valid user credentials for Azure
- If this is the first time using my web app, Azure asks the user to grant permissions to their Azure AD information
- After accepting the permissions, Azure redirects to the reply URL that I've set up in Azure AD for my application, but it replies with the aforementioned error in the URL string

The application itself is a Node.js web app that uses the [Passport module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) for Azure AD authentication, although I don't think Passport is the source of the problem because the error I get is passed by Azure to the web application's reply URL.

I haven't had luck identifying the source, but I have seen [posts from people with similar issues](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84e6dbd9-d35a-4092-8c68-9c261ceecf95/aad-oauth-login-suddenly-started-failing-with-aadsts70002-error-validating-credentials-aadsts50012?forum=WindowsAzureAD&prof=required). I have a number of AD accounts that I use both personally and for work, and it seems that there is some remnant left in the browser's cache or local storage that causes this issue because I can switch to another browser or into incognito mode and the problem resolves itself.

I'd like to identify if this is a problem with Azure itself, the way my application handles authentication, or with my work/third party applications implement AD authentication.

Comment: I've also seen some people hitting this problem recently. Id like to investigate if possible. Could you post the correlationId and timestamp, as well as your app's clientId? I believe the source of the problem does indeed relate to residual cookies

Comment: Oh and if you do have a consistent repro, posting the cookies being sent to login.msftonline.com would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce this issue using the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect.git) in Chrome, however failed.

Based on the same issue link you mentioned, I noticed that the endpoint for he/she using was incorrect. To develop the multi-tenant app, we need to change the specific endpoint with common like below:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/

Were you using the specific endpoint? If not, would you mind sharing a code sample to help us to reproduce this issue?